# WFS data expiration check

Tags: wfs

Does WFS protocol offer a way to know when layer/featureType data was last modified?

If not, is there another protocol that allows retrieving such information?

Comment: Not directly. The one who maintains the data can of course add and update a "last_modified" attribute and users can utilize that for filtering.

Comment: @user30184: Tnx! That of course. I wonder if there isn't a protocol which allows to expose say a "last_modified" general property, to inform the client of the fact the data in the layer has somehow changed and the layer needs to be invalidated.

Comment: Well, there was an OGC plan of versioning WFS and Geoserver did implement it somehow. Unfortunately many links do not work at the moment but this does http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/programming-guide/versioning/wfsv/samplecalls.html. It has never been production ready I fear. This one may interest you too, it is about using Merkle Trees and SHA-1 checksums for analyzing fast what all has changed http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Propose-a-new-community-module-geoserver-sync-td5093282.html.